# Cant add plugin in poetry

Tags: python-3.8, python-poetry

I have initialized `poetry` in my project. Add some libs and got this `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "dataapi"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "API for service."
authors = ["Claus Stolz"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
gino = "^1.0.1"
fastapi = "^0.63.0"
uvicorn = "^0.13.3"
gunicorn = "^20.0.4"
alembic = "^1.5.2"
psycopg2 = "^2.8.6"
gino-starlette = "^0.1.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^6.2.1"
requests = "^2.25.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Now i try to add in `pyproject.toml` my own plugin to use it like entry points in code:

```
[tool.poetry.plugins."dataapi.modules"]
users = "dataapi.app.api.v1.endpoints.users"
```

Then try to use `poetry install`, but it give me message:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

I try another methods of `poetry`: `update`,`lock`, but nothing happened. I tried to delete the lock file and then run `poetry install` - but it gave no results either.

I run my service to check and it give me an error:

```
for ep in entry_points()["dataapi.modules"]:
KeyError: 'dataapi.modules'
```

Method where i try to got entry points:

```
import logging
from importlib.metadata import entry_points

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def load_modules(app=None):
    for ep in entry_points()["dataapi.modules"]:
        logger.info("Loading module: %s", ep.name)
        mod = ep.load()
        if app:
            init_app = getattr(mod, "init_app", None)
            if init_app:
                init_app(app)
```

I really don't understood how add plugin in poetry and need help...

Comment: It might be a bug... What happens if you recreate the virtual environment from scratch. Or if you bump the version number?

Comment: Also I noticed you are missing the name of a function. The notation is `entry_point_name = top_level_package.package:function`. Instead of `function` I guess it could also be a class, or a variable, but I am pretty sure there should be a `:` and something else after.

Comment: If i recreate or change version number - nothing happens.

Comment: About The notation is `entry_point_name = top_level_package.package:function.`. 
I guess that this is not the problem. Because I want to get exactly the whole module, and not a special class or variable.

Comment: I see... -- Different approach: If you build a _sdist_ and open it, is there a `setup.py` file in the _sdist_ and how does it look like?